# Mime types on WP8 Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, mime-types, html, plaintext

I have a web service in my home network that shows a dummy plain text content, say "Hello world!". Mime type of http content is text/plain.

I can see this phrase from my browser on pc, but not from Windows Phone browser - it tries to save/open it and can't find an app in the market for this purpose.

I found some relevant but incomplete tips here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622940(v=vs.85).aspx

What should I do to see plain text web page in IE mobile on WP8?

Comment: Details: first, I posted "Hello world!" from django wrapper and it showed ok on WP. Then 1 of 2 things ruined it:

* either me switching from django to web.py so that django's wrapper didn't add something up to my text OR
* IE mobile got an update, which is rather unlikely

Answer (score 0):

IE mobile doesn't show text/plain content, AFAIK.

So on my server I just changed mime type of response to text/html with same output.

And it worked )